# Is 60Hz refresh rate as bad as I believe it is?

Tags: refresh-rate

I decided to upgrade my monitor, from current 19" LG Flatron L1919S to a new 24" [BENQ GL2440HM](http://www.benq.com.au/products/product_detail.cfm?product=1796&pltag=2&ptag=197). However, the BENQ one has a max. refresh rate of `60Hz`. My monitor currently runs at 75 Hz, and when I changed to 60Hz to see how bad it is, it was really really bad. I can't keep that rate more than 5 seconds because it hurts my eyes. The question is: Will be the same quality at 60Hz on a 24" fullHD (1920x1080) monitor as it is on a 19" 1280x1024 monitor?

Comment: Go to a store and see for yourself. Some people can handle it, some can't.

Comment: unfortunately i can't do that.

Comment: was the LG a CRT screen?

Comment: @Sathya 19" TFT 1280x1024, 2000:1 contrast, 300cd/m2 brightness, 5ms time according to German Amazon.

Comment: Unfortunately, Daniel's comment is right. I've been using 60 Hz monitors for 13 years now and never had any problems with them. On the other hand, I've seen people have serious problems with them too.

Comment: @AndrejaKo - I cannot handle 60Hz *CRT* screens. LCDs - however is a different matter altogether

Comment: @Sathya♦ I never had problems with either.

Comment: @develroot I edited my answer. I did not realize they did not produce flicker at all. Sorry for the mistake.

Comment: i'm not sure. i'm using an LCD monitor, and if I change the res to 60Hz it's horrible. Anyway, i'll try to find a person who owns that monitor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You hit on the exact problem with low refresh rates, but as Sathya points out, this is only for CRT monitors since they flicker, but LCD's don't: For many people, they can hurt the eyes. 75MHz is usually a minimum.

The biggest issue for you would then be if you are a gamer, or run other applications that may require a fast refresh rate. If you are a gamer, I would defintely visit a gaming site, and get recommendations there.

General advice: Many monitors come with driver disks that tell the computer what resolutions and refresh rates it can take. If yours does, make sure your monitor is using that driver instead of the default.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Refresh_rate

Comment: I could've sworn refresh rate has no bearing for TFT/LCD panels

Comment: currently i have'nt bought it yet. I don't want to make the bad choice because for me it means a lot of money. and as i mentioned, i would like to run it at 1920x1080 pixels

Comment: @Sathya You are right...they don't produce flicker...I will edit my answer. I defintely have made a few mistakes in my answers sonce I have been here, but while I would prefer not to make them, at least when I do, they get pointed out, and I learn something new.

Comment: 75 MHz refresh rate?  Not likely.

Comment: @BenVoigt highly unlikely.