# Is 75Hz monitor technology still evolving?

Tags: display, resolution, refresh-rate

I was looking for some budget 75Hz monitors because I felt they would be little bit better than typical 60Hz monitor.

I mainly considered Full HD 22" IPS monitors.

Then I came to know about a lot of things that monitor brands or sellers don't clarify. I downloaded user manuals of various known brands like Samsung, LG, Acer for most of their 75Hz monitors.

For example, most 75Hz monitors I found on Amazon (India) show 75Hz refresh rate on product specifications, but when I cross checked their user manuals, you see the real truth:

Samsung would mention something like this:

`Optimal Resolution: 1920x1080@60Hz`

`Maximum Resolution: 1920x1080@75Hz`

LG would mention something like this:

`Recommended Resolution: 1920x1080@60Hz`

`Maximum Resolution: 1920x1080@75Hz`

Acer also mentioned similar terminology where they claimed to support 75Hz but still recommended 60Hz.

Further, some Acer monitors user manuals had mentioned 75Hz only when *FreeSync* is enabled. That is, it will work mainly on AMD graphics cards.

**Interestingly**, some Acer monitors also supported 75Hz only for lower resolutions only. 75Hz wasn't possible at all for 60Hz. So it was purely a marketing strategy.

Note: Of course there some 24" 75Hz products from some other brands like Asus/Benq where they didn't mention as such "60Hz recommendation". But they were 30-50% more expensive.

---

Now I find it hard to understand why they don't recommend **75Hz** instead?

Personally, I feel there could be one of following reasons:

- 75Hz is still evolving (except in some expensive monitors which I manage to find from Benq and HP). So these brands are not yet 'confident' to recommend them.
- Maybe 75Hz for LED/LCD monitors became popular in recent years only. So it is possible they entirely had focused on 60Hz monitors before (for this budget) and later realized they might sell more if they focus on 75Hz. So maybe they did some "quick changes" in their existing designs and started marketing them as 75Hz monitors.
- (More likely) 75Hz has already evolved and brands are comfortable in producing such monitors, but that would increase the cost. So they still recommend 60Hz while still aiming to market "sort of 75Hz" monitors for budget customers.
- Power saving. But I would understand it more easily if it were a laptop.

---

In short, I don't understand that when we buy a 60Hz monitor, it supports 60Hz out of the box and it is recommended in most cases. But in case of these budget (entry level) 75Hz monitors, they still recommend 60Hz. **I feel like they are not confident in their technology.**

Given all that, is 75Hz monitor technology still evolving or is it purely a budget and customers oriented strategy? Or could there be any other reason?

Comment: Evolving? We shot past 75Hz many years ago, why would we "evolve" back to something worse?

Comment: I think the question you wanted to ask is "Can these monitors run at 75Hz without problems".

Comment: @gronostaj maybe but then it would become to a brand specific. One brand might give a "go ahead" and other might not. The main reason I asked this because it is true for well known brands especially for entry level 75Hz monitors. It appears purely a marketing strategy or they simply don't fully believe they would perform good at 75Hz.

Comment: But seeing the comment above, looks like one doubt is clear. It's definitely not evolution related problem. They can definitely design 75Hz monitors without any problem.

Comment: They can make 75Hz monitors but the question is whether it is worth it. 60Hz produces a new image every 16.6 milliseconds, whole 75Hz only takes that down to 13.3 milliseconds. It is not a particularly noticeable improvement compared to actually doubling up to 120Hz or beyond, and as LPChip mentioned could look worse if the backlight has a flicker at 50/60 hz due to mains hum.

Comment: "could look worse" you mean the 120Hz monitor or 60Hz / 75Hz monitor? @Mokubai

Comment: @gronostaj I will ask *that* question too, soon ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are way past 75hz. There are monitors that do 144hz and higher. It is a race for the best although going past 250hz seems to not give a huge benefit.

Going to a higher refreshrate comes with a few challenges though.

To be able to enjoy the high refreshrate of a monitor, the content on screen also needs to reach the same or higher amount of frames per second. This means, the computer must be powerful enough.

In addition, to get the smoothest experience, you can enable vsync. Vsync combines the FPS with the refreshrate. Now, if you play a game that can do 75fps with vsync on, the result should be optimal, right?

The problem is that all modern displays are set to 60hz because the power AC/DC conversion also happens to 60hz or 50hz depending on where you are in the world. Because 60hz with vsync on on a powersystem with 60hz, manufacturers keep saying in their manual that 60hz is the most optimal resolution to use, and it is true.

75hz does work, and works well enough, but it can't match the 60hz experience.

120hz monitors however, double that frequency, so 120hz is definitely better than 60hz in all aspects, assuming you can also reach 120FPS.

Above 120hz, because the frames are already atleast once present per powercycle, the whole AC/DC conversion is not a big issue anymore, which is why 144hz is also an acceptable refreshrate.

I have a 100hz refreshrate on a 50hz powerline and it is definitely better than 60hz. But I also have a 85hz monitor and it is only marginally better than 60hz because I'm on a 50hz powerline. Would I be on a 60hz powerline, the 60hz would've been better.

Comment: It looks like [majority of world's population](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mains_electricity_by_country) has 50 Hz mains. Does it mean they are screwed? And actually 75 Hz is closer to ideal than 60 Hz? What about adaptive sync? What are the effects of sub-optimal setup, exactly?

Comment: As far as I know, the 240V instead of 120V compensates for it, and if I'm not mistaken it is 3 phases rather than 2 which also reduces the problem a bit. But all I know is that most displays are 60hz here with 50hz timing on the mains, and never really had an issue with it. Adaptive sync would try to limit the FPS to a multiple of 30 depending on what FPS you get, so it should be less of an issue there, but I've also had monitors with weird 59hz stuff, and there I could definitely see flicker etc.

Comment: Ah. I didn't know power frequency is also involved in this. BTW I just checked my country (India) have 50Hz power. So in that case, it doesn't really matter whether it is 60Hz or 75Hz refresh rate, right? Or the 60Hz refresh rate still would be better? I'm not sure if I understood it correctly.

Comment: I'd say it will matter less, yes. But if possible, you should look for a 100Hz display or higher.

Comment: @LPChip because 100Hz = 50Hz x 2? So that way, 50Hz monitor would also technically work the "best"? (Of course less smooth than 100Hz)

Comment: Yes, except there are virtually no 50hz monitors and a lot more 100hz monitors. 100hz is much easier on the eyes than both 50hz and 60hz.

Comment: Hmm. Regarding the "easy on eyes" have mixed views from people. See comments and answer here https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/108002/is-50hz-noticably-worse-for-eyes-than-60hz-on-a-4k-monitor and here https://superuser.com/questions/302415/is-60hz-refresh-rate-as-bad-as-i-believe-it-is

Comment: Is 60Hz really bad especially for eyes?

Comment: 60Hz has just become a standard. It is no longer dependent on the mains frequency. That went out with LCD television, PAL & NTSC. Even CRT displays weren't tied to it & in fact CRTs look pretty bad at 60 [because peripheral vision could see the flicker, which of course doesn't happen on LCD] so often ran higher. 75 or 85Hz was pretty standard for a couple of decades.